# Video not visible

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I want to add a background video in `Next.js` on homepage. When I check through inspect element, background video is there; but it is not visible.

How can I solve this?

Open the snippet to see my example code in a `stack snippet`.

```js
//export not allowed in stack snippet
function Home() {
    const name = "Yo";
    return (
        <div className="styles-from-page-module-file">
            <video
                id="background-video"
                loop
                autoPlay
                muted
                style={{
                    position: "relative",
                    objectFit: "cover",
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "15rem",
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0,
                }}>
                <source
                    src="https://webcode.tools/media/video.mp4"
                    type="video/mp4"
                />
            </video>
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Which browser and OS you're using to develop?

Comment: Have you tried to copy the mp4 file to /public/assets folder?